# How to handle nested browserify projects

Tags: javascript, browserify

I have 2 projects, let's call them project A and project B.

Project A is used by many other projects and runs both on a server and client. So to run the code in the browser we use browserify to package the code.

Project B is also a clientside project, and needs the clientside functionality of Project A. However, trying to `require` the browserified package of project A in project B and then browserifying project B leads to failure. Browserify tries to resolve all the `requires` in the Project A bundle.

I've looked through the configuration options and it's not really clear to me what I need to do to make this work (or perhaps Browserify was not meant to handle cases like this).

Comment: Could you not require the original files from Project A?

Comment: What kind of errors are you receiving?